# html form submitted with null values

Tags: asp.net, forms, sharepoint-2010, httprequest

I have a small form within asp.net page with Method attribute="post" and the on Codebehinde, i want to access form values like this: string val = Request.form["field"]; But when i put breakpoint and check, it returns null value. But i have put values into input textbox and press submit button. I could not understand why it returns null. Can anybody explain what is problem.

Comment: Can you post code please? We will be able to help you much better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are are using `runat="server"` on the textbox so the name of it in the Form collection will be probably be something like "ctl00_srchtxtx".

Make the `<input>` into `<asp:TextBox>` and use `string val = srchtxtx.Text;` instead.
You should also add `runat="server"` to your form, or you will probably get other issues.

Or if this cannot be a server form remove runat="server" from the `<input>`.

Comment: i could not find .Text property of srchtxtx Control. But i tried with string val = srchtxtx.value; instead, but it returns empty string.

Comment: Probably because the form is not a server form, so it does not set up the control properties correctly in the codebehind.

Comment: Due to some reasons, i could not use <asp:TextBox>.I have remove runat="server" from <input>, but still it returns empty string. any idea to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

It works perfect while assuming runat = "server" as:

string val = Request.Form[srchtxtx.UniqueID];